# Is there a way to setup SSL on heroku-godaddy using letsencrpyt entirely for free?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, lets-encrypt

I've been an amateur developer for quite some time now and this is the first time I've actually needed to set up the domain and SSL for a website. I already bought a domain name from GoDaddy and I'm using my rails as my backend. But it seems that on almost all of the guides online (the ones I've come to search) is for the Heroku paid dynos (I'm on the free tier) or has their website hosted somewhere else/bought the domain somewhere else. As of now, I'm not actually sure how straightforward this should be but any guide to free SSL cert generation and free setup would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here:

1. Use Heroku domain `app.herokuapp.com` as this is encrypted and served through https.
2. If you want to use a custom domain. There is no way but to use a paid dyno. There were some tutorials on how to do this manually and a couple of projects that allowed you to do so on free dynos but they are all outdated/deprecated.

There is no need to configure anything on Heroku's side if you start off with a paid dyno.

> ACM is enabled by default for all Common Runtime apps created after March 21, 2017 that run on Hobby or Professional dynos.

To upgrade, simply run `heroku ps:resize web=hobby` via heroku cli. Then, to enable letsencrypt automated certificate, simply run `heroku certs:auto:enable`. **Just make sure your DNS is activly pointing to the currect address before doing so or you'll need to verify your DNS target.**

Docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management

deprecated project: https://github.com/dmathieu/sabayon

outdated tutorial: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-heroku/blob/master/SSL-certificate-step-by-step-setup-instructions.md

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same setup for my heroku app. By default **heroku free tier gives ssl on your web app**.

Like if you hit url **yourwebsite.herokuapp.com**, it is encrypted and provides ssl for free.

But when you will add a custom domain name to your heroku app, **then its without ssl.** You cannot use ssl on it unless you moved to hobby dyno(paid)

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/understanding-ssl-on-heroku#when-to-use-automated-certificate-management-acm) is what heroku says

Comment: is there no way to do this other than paid dynos? Even with other hosting sites/tools/approaches?

Comment: just use heroku default url for your web app. like yourwebsite.herokuapp.com

Comment: the problem is I want to use my bought domain from godaddy

Comment: Is your app accessible via your purchased domain?

Comment: I believe you cannot use it free, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/understanding-ssl-on-heroku#when-to-use-automated-certificate-management-acm

Comment: So as an end note: if I have a godaddy domain, letsencrypt SSL cert, and a paid dynos from heroku, I can succesfully implement SSL while only paying for the domain from godaddy and dynos from heroku?